# What happens to water and oxygen produced due to dissociation of nitric acid?

Tags: acid-base, water, solubility, nitro-compounds

Nitric acid is yellow in colour due to the dissolution of nitrogen dioxide gas.

The nitrogen dioxide is obtained due to thermal dissociation of a portion of nitric acid:

$$\ce{4HNO3 -> 2H2O + 4NO2 + O2}$$

The nitrogen dioxide produced after dissociation dissolves in $\ce{HNO3}$ but what happens to the $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{O2}$ produced?

Shouldn't some $\ce{HNO3}$ dissolve in water as it is highly soluble? And if it does dissolve than what happens to the dissolved nitric acid?

In my book nothing is given as to what happens to the $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{O2}$.
So what exactly happens to $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{O2}$?

Comment: Having done this many years ago, using an actual retort, you get nitric acid in the chilled receiving vessel. Any oxygen produced the equation you gave simply goes into the atmosphere. Same for some water vapor; the remaining water is simply in the receiving vessel.